# Web plateform installer does not contain management service

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, deployment, web-platform-installer

I want to publish MVC project on Plesk hosting(godady server). For this I go to `visual studio > Build > Publish` but i'm receiving error `Web management service is not started`. Detailed error is:[image]

Then I downloaded `Web plateform installer` to add `IIS Management Service` but it does not contain `IIS Management Service`. [image]

Whats wrong why it does not contain `IIS Management Service` or what is its alternative?

Answer (score 0):

You need following packages to install via Web PI-

[Web Deploy](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy) 3.5 or 3.6(latest)
Web Deploy 3.5 without bundled SQL support.

Web Management service gets installed with Web deploy tooling. After installation you can verify in services if it's started properly on target machine.

Comment: Ok I downloaded and installed web deploy 3.5. Then I go to services, it does not contain `Web management service`. Then I opened `Deployment wizard` (Desktop app) it gives error. `To launch the Integration Services Deployment wizard, one of the components: Integration Services, Management Tools - Basic or Business Intelligence Development Studio has to be installed by the SQL Server 2012 Standard, Enterprise, Developer, or Evaluation Edition. To install a component, run SQL Server Setup and select the component name.`

Comment: Have u installed the second one as well? Also make sure both the machines Development and where you're deploying both have the Deploy tools installed.

Comment: No. i didn't find link for second one. Please provide a link

Comment: You can search it from WebPI tool. Searching for `Web Deploy` will bring up both tools in the results. One more thing.. I would recommend to install these tools from WebPI if there's any dependency required for these tools the WebPI will automatically include them for installation. I have done it many time which is why I'm very confident about this problem.

Comment: and where i can find webPI tool?

Comment: It's the same tool which you posted in second screen shot `Web Platform installer`

Comment: ok `Web Deploy 3.5 without bundled SQL support` is already installed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110675/discussion-between-vendettamit-and-irfan-wattoo).